# Daisy does not take vector of categorical variables

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I am trying to use hierarchical clustering with mixed data, but I can't use the `daisy` function from the `cluster` package. I am a beginner with R so this is probably an easy question. I will describe a sample set with my problem since the dataset I am using is very large. Please bear with me.

I have my dataframe `df` which has two columns `df$colA` (numeric variable) and `df$colB` (categorical variable). `df$colA` was made in such a way that both the type and class of `df$colA` are "integer", and both the type and class of `df$colB` are character.

When calling `daisy(df, metric = "gower")`, I had the error `invalid type character for column numbers 2`, and searching online I saw that I had to change `df$colB` to `as.factor(df$colB)`, but now I get the error: `Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric`.

I have isolated the problem to `df$colB` so I tried to obtain the Gower distance matrix through `daisy` for the data frame consisting of `df$colB` as its only column and it gave the same error. Now, if I make some sample data frame `test_df <- data.frame(test_column = c('A','B','C'))`, which also has a class of factor and type integer, I have no problems obtaining the Gower distance matrix, so I don't know what to do anymore.

I did check that there were no `NA` values in the vector as well.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your data? Perhaps with `dput(head(df, 10))` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce your error using the dataset from cluster; library(cluster); data(flower); flower$V4 = factor(flower$V4) ; daisy(flower,metric="gower")

Comment: I think there's something weird with your df, please follow GSW's suggestion and do dput(head(df,10))